# "No member named" incomplete type in multi-level CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, crtp, static-polymorphism

I have encountered an incomplete type error in designing my library's CRTP inheritance structure. I am cognizant of the fact that this might possibly be solved by way of type traits but I do not even know where to begin and would like some guidance in that regard.

Roughly speaking, `Alg` and `Geo` are two interfaces that inherit from a shared base. `Alg` is fairly straightforward but `Geo` is a bit more complex in that it takes as a template parameter a class deriving from `Alg`. The incomplete type error is in reference to this functionality. [Minimal reproducible example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ee5b6075cd9bbe1)

The following skeleton illustrates the problem at hand.

```
template <typename Derived>
struct FitCRTP {
    Derived& derived() { return static_cast<Derived&>(*this); }
    Derived const& derived() const { return static_cast<Derived const&>(*this); }
};

template <typename Derived>
class FitBase : public FitCRTP<Derived> {
    friend class FitCRTP<Derived>;
    
    protected:
        FitBase() {}
        explicit FitBase(const Matrix& data) {
            this->derived().fit(data);
        }
};

template <typename Derived> 
class Alg : public FitBase<Derived> {
    friend class FitBase<Derived>;

    public:
        void fit (const Matrix& data) { 
            this->derived().compute(data);
        }

    protected:
        // constructors and misc functions ...
    }
};

template <typename Derived, class A,
    class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Alg<A>, A>>> 
    class Geo : public FitBase<Geo<Derived, A>> {
        friend class FitBase<Geo<Derived, A>>;

        public:
            void fit (const Matrix& data) {        
                this->derived().compute(data, A(data).getGuess());    // <-- Problem line!
            }

        protected:
            // constructors and misc functions ...
        }
    };
```

Below is an example of one of `A`'s derived classes and a usage example.

```
template <class A>
class SpathSVD : public Geo<SpathSVD<A>, A> {
    friend class Geo<SpathSVD<A>, A>;
    typedef Geo<SpathSVD<A>, A> Base;
public:
    SpathSVD<A> : Base() {}
    SpathSVD<A> (const Matrix& data) : Base(data) {}

protected:
    SpathSVD& compute (const Matrix& data, Guess g) {
        // Algorithm implementation ...
    }
}

int main() {
    SpathSVD<SomeAlgVariant> S;
    S.fit(data);
}
```

The error occurs because the `compute` function cannot be found in `Geo<SpathSVD<SomeAlgVariant>, SomeAlgVariant>`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hmm, when I try to compile your code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/137a64c02f5d3daa) with g++ (c++17), I get a bunch more error messages. Can you post a [mcve] that exactly reproduces your error please.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the base classes, thank you for pointing out my omission. I am also working on the MRE and will have that shortly.

Comment: A bit of context could help too: what are you trying to model? Some kind of solver parametrized on some algorithmic variants? Why have you chosen CRTP?

Comment: I am a graduate student and this library will be used to study an incredibly niche application of errors-in-variable problems. Many of the algorithms can be separated into well-defined categories -- and often rely on initial guesses provided by counterparts of a related, but fundamentally different variety -- and so I feel that CRTP's extensibility is particularly well-suited to this use case

Comment: Also, please see the attached example in the updated post.

Comment: @TomPorter The provided example fails to compile for many reasons, and I have not yet seen the error you asked about. I have seen: `Matrix` not declared, `Guess` not declared, `SomeAlgVariant` not declared, missing semicolon, extra closing brace, etc. Please make sure the example you post actually demonstrates the issue you are asking about. Online compilers can be useful for this (especially since that is what we are likely to use to look at your code). There is a list in the [C++ tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) (I tend to use [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/)).

Comment: @TomPorter PS: I only looked at the example code in your question, as that is where your [mre] belongs.